# VB.Net check for existing keys in a collection

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

I have a class that inherits from the `CollectionBase` and when adding items I want to detect whether the collection already contains the key that is going to be inserted. If it does I want to send a warning via a MsgBox(). Here is the code & what I've tried

```
<Serializable()> Public Class validationList
    Inherits CollectionBase

    Public Function Add(ByVal Item As validationItem) As Integer
        MsgBox(Me.List.Contains(Item))
        Return Me.List.Add(Item)
    End Function

    Default Public ReadOnly Property Item(ByVal index As Integer) As validationItem
        Get
            Return CType(List.Item(index), validationItem)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub Remove(ByVal index As Integer)
        Me.List.RemoveAt(index)
    End Sub

    Public Function IndexOf(ByVal key As validationItem)
        Return List.IndexOf(key)
    End Function

    Public Sub AddRange(ByVal item() As validationItem)
        For counter As Integer = 0 To item.GetLength(0) - 1
            List.Add(item(counter))
        Next
    End Sub
End Class

<Serializable()> Public Class validationItem
    Private _key As validationTypes
    Private _value As String

    Public Enum validationTypes
        man = 0
        num = 1
    End Enum

    Public Property Value As String
        Get
            Return _value
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _value = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Key As validationTypes
        Get
            Return _key
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As validationTypes)
            _key = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        ' Empty constructor is needed for serialization
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal k As validationTypes, ByVal v As String)
        _key = k
        _value = v
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class textbox
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    Private _validation As New validationList

    <System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility(Content)>
    Public Property validation As validationList
        Get
            Return _validation
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As validationList)
            _validation = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

In the add method I tried to check whether the collection already has this item. But it always returns `-1`.

Here is code that adds a new item to the collection

```
Textbox1.validation.Add(New validationItem With {.Key = validationItem.validationTypes.man, .Value = "1"})
```

Comment: I built this according to an answer provided to a previous question and the member who answered it mentioned that I am better of using a collection that a dictionary because this is exposed in the designer via a property.

Answer (score 2):

To make [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) work, you'll have to implement `Equals`/`GetHashCode` on `validationItem` or implement the [`IEquatable(Of T)` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1):

> This method determines equality by using the default equality comparer, as defined by the object's implementation of the IEquatable(Of T).Equals method for T (the type of values in the list).

Here's an example implementation for `Equals`/`GetHashCode` that checks both, `Key` and `Value`:

```
<Serializable> _
Public Class validationItem

    Protected Overloads Function Equals(other As validationItem) As Boolean
        Return _value = other._value AndAlso _key = other._key
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
        If obj Is Nothing Then
            Return False
        End If
        If Me Is obj Then
            Return True
        End If
        If obj.GetType() IsNot Me.GetType() Then
            Return False
        End If
        Return Equals(DirectCast(obj, validationItem))
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
        Return ((If(_value IsNot Nothing, _value.GetHashCode(), 0)) * 397) Xor CInt(_key)
    End Function

    ...

End Class
```

You could also use use LINQ, here's an example that only checks for `Key`:

```
Public Function Add(ByVal Item As validationItem) As Integer
    If Me.List.OfType(Of validationItem).Any(Function(i) i.Key = Item.Key) Then
        ' Do something '
    Else
        Return Me.List.Add(Item)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I tried to use IEquatable(Of T), it gives me false positives don't know why. I posted a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24362981/vb-net-check-for-duplicate-items-in-a-collection-base.. Upvoted for introducting IEquatable(Of T).

Answer (score -1):

You need to just check for whether the key exist or not and only show it if it exists:

```
Public Function Add(ByVal Item As validationItem) As Integer
    If Me.List.Contains(Item) Then MsgBox("The key already exists")
    Return Me.List.Add(Item)
End Function
```

As it stands you are just returning the result of the `Contains` method which is a `Boolean` (hence the `-1`)

Comment: I already have the item with the key "man" before adding it via the code but it still returns -1. I know there should be a If condition in place, I just added the message box to see the returning value.