# VB.Net check for duplicate items in a collection base

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

I have a class that inherits from CollectionBase. I tried to use the contains method to detect whether the Key already exists before inserting a new one. Here is what I have tried.

```
<Serializable()> Public Class validationList
    Inherits CollectionBase

    Public Function Add(ByVal Item As validationItem) As Integer
        Return Me.List.Add(Item)
    End Function

    Default Public ReadOnly Property Item(ByVal index As Integer) As validationItem
        Get
            Return CType(List.Item(index), validationItem)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub Remove(ByVal index As Integer)
        Me.List.RemoveAt(index)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnInsert(ByVal index As Integer, ByVal value As Object)
        If Me.List.Contains(value) Then MsgBox("Already exist")
        MyBase.OnInsert(index, value)
    End Sub

    Public Function IndexOf(ByVal key As validationItem)
        Return List.IndexOf(key)
    End Function

    Public Sub AddRange(ByVal item() As validationItem)
        For counter As Integer = 0 To item.GetLength(0) - 1
            List.Add(item(counter))
        Next
    End Sub
End Class

<Serializable()> Public Class validationItem
    Implements IEquatable(Of validationItem)

    Private _key As validationTypes
    Private _value As String

    Public Sub New()
        ' Empty constructor is needed for serialization
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal k As validationTypes, ByVal v As String)
        _key = k
        _value = v
    End Sub

    Public Enum validationTypes
        Madatory = 0
        [Integer] = 1
        Numeric = 2
        [Decimal] = 3
        MaxValue = 4
        MinValue = 5
        MinLength = 6
        Email = 7
    End Enum

    Public Property Value As String
        Get
            Return _value
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _value = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Key As validationTypes
        Get
            Return _key
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As validationTypes)
            _key = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overloads Function Equals(ByVal eqItem As validationItem) As Boolean Implements IEquatable(Of Testing_Project.validationItem).Equals
        If eqItem Is Nothing Then Return False
        Return Me._key = eqItem.Key
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function Equals(ByVal eqItem As Object) As Boolean
        If eqItem Is Nothing Then Return False
        Dim eqItemObj As validationItem = TryCast(eqItem, validationItem)
        If eqItemObj Is Nothing Then Return False
        Return Equals(eqItemObj)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
        Return Me._key.GetHashCode()
    End Function
End Class
```

The validationList will be exposed from a usercontrol as a property, so that items could be added from the designer. When adding items I need to detect whether they already exist. I tried overriding the OnInsert but this sometime return that duplicates exists even when their aren't and doesn't report that duplicate exist when I try to add existing keys.

Comment: Have you used the debugger? Side-note: do you really find `Return If(Me._key = eqItem.Key, True, False)` more readable than `Return _key = eqItem.Key`?

Comment: The code should work fine. Maybe that's some issue with the designer? If you hit a false positive, attach a debugger to Visual Studio and see what's going on.

Comment: I found the issue but don't know how to fix it. On the OnInsert overridden Method I checked to see what Keys are being saved to the collection and they are all 0's.. And sometimes when I view the collection from the designer all the items are gone.

Comment: The problem is whenever I add an item it identified the Key = 0 & Value = Nothing. I checked from the debugger..

Comment: OnInsert: `Performs additional custom processes before inserting a new element into the System.Collections.CollectionBase instance.` This is not the place to reject duplicates.  EVERYTHING will be added to the collection via Add/AddRange (collection editor and designer serialization), so you can test there for a dupe and decline to add it.  IEquatable will work but is overkill.  Also [Collection<T> is recommended over CollectionBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169389(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: validationList cannot be inherited by Collection. Where do you suggest that I need to change.

Comment: (Inheriting from `Collection(of T)` comes with a free built in Contains, Add and Item methods).   `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of T)` **not** the awful VisualBasic Collection

Comment: I cannot inherit from Collection it says 'validationList' cannot inherit from class 'Collection' because 'Collection' is declared 'NotInheritable'. Sry. I'm new to this...!

Comment: wrong collection.  `Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel` and `Inherits Collection(Of validationITEM)`  may also have to add a reference to the assembly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This indirectly answers the question after dealing with the issue which emerged in comments about `Collection(Of T)`:

Add a reference to `System.Collections.ObjectModel` if needed, then

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

' a ValidationItem collection class 
Public Class ValidationItems
    Inherits Collection(Of ValidationItem)

    Public Shadows Sub Add(NewItem As ValidationItem)
        ' test for existence 
        ' do not add if it is not unique

        Dim dupe As Boolean = False
        For n As Int32 = 0 To Items.Count - 1
            If Items(n).Key = NewItem.Key Then
                dupe = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If dupe = False then
            items.Add(newitem)
        End if

        ' I would actually use an IndexOfKey function which might
        ' be useful elsewhere and only add if the return is -1 
        If IndexOfKey(NewItem.Key) <> -1 Then
            Items.Add(newItem)
        End If

    End Sub
```

Some NET collection types implement `Add` as a function and return the item added.  This sounds weird since you pass it the item to add.  But returning Nothing if the item cannot be added is a neat semaphore for "I cant/wont do that".  I cant recall if the std NET Collection Editor recognizes that or not.

One problem with using `Contains` is that it will test if `item` passed as param is the same object as one in the list.  They never will be **the same object**, even if they have the same values.  Testing the key in a loop is simpler than calling a method which implements an interface. (That previous answer was totally valid in the context presented, but the context has changed).

Even if you stay with CollectionBase, you want to handle it in the `Add`.  If you try to remove it in `OnInsert`, VS will have problems deserializing the collection.

Also, your `validationitem` needs a Name property or the Collection Editor will display "Myassembly+MyType" as the Name (or a ToString override).

Other issues:

- I am not sure your `IndexOf` will work.  The list contains ValidationItems (objects), but you check it for `_key` (string).  This will not matter if you change to `Collection(Of T)` which implements it for you.
- The simple ctor is needed by the Collection Editor, not serialization.  But the important thing is that it is there.
- As for the comment about all Zeroes coming back - that is because your ValidationItem is not yet decorated for designer serialization.  Maybe not the Collection *Property* either, that isnt shown.

Comment: I have done the designer serialization in the usercontrol.

Private _validation As New validationList

    <System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility(Content)>
    Public Property Validation As validationList
        Get
            Return _validation
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As validationList)
            _validation = value
        End Set
    End Property

Comment: I had to add the Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel.. I made the changes as you suggested thanks. After adding the items I checked to see the values of the Key available in the collection. Why is everything 0. I know you answered it in the last point Under Other issues but I didn't understand it.

Comment: go back to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24309995/1070452) and add the attributes to your Item class which are present on `FooBar`.  Your items will be contained in a collection thru a collection property.  VS/NET needs information on how to serialize those "buried" items.  This is provided via the <Attributes> (and a TypeConverter which will likely be a forthcoming question).

Comment: the Collection **Property** needs what you have in the first comment but the collection ITEMS also need attributes decorating them since they are the actual data.  VB/VS needs to recreate your collection - deserialize it - everytime it runs including the data it contains.  there really is not much fluff or overkill in that Dictionary related answer.  I have a FooBar, you have a ValidationItem, but otherwise they are very similar

Comment: I am now trying back the answer provided in the FooBar. You've been a great help this thing is driving me nutzz...

Comment: we are off on a tangent and is difficult to provide help on serialization issues without seeing the current code state.  I suggest a new question for that - is the duplicate detection working now?

Comment: No still trying, I know it is difficult to answer, I'm having a hard time explaining the exact question... :) If I do the way as suggested on the FooBar solution I don't need to have the ValidationList class right...

Comment: incorrect.  Your ValidationItems class - the collection class - is analogous to the List<T> I used in the old answer.  You need that and that is what is exposed as a Collection Property on the UserControl.  This class should inherit Collection<T> and do the work of detecting dupes presumably in the Add method. Maybe update your post ADDING the current code (dont replace or it invalidates my answer)

Comment: Shall I edit this question & add my current code ? what do you mean by dont replace..

Comment: i mean dont change the original question.  Add a new para about changing to CollectionT, here is what I have now: then replace the code.  otehrwise my answer makes no sense

Comment: added some code in ADD for detecting Dupes @crazy_PHP_MAN

Comment: ok.. After updating the collection on the designer gets cleared after debugging. I will update the question in a moment..

Comment: there are 2 or 3 possible reasons for that but it is a seriualization issue, lets fix the dupe part since that is the topic of this question.  you will also want to CLEAN and REBUILD the USerControl after every change so that VS can compile your code and see the changes

Comment: Ok. but I cant test whether the dupe part is working without being able to add items to the collection..

Comment: Ahhh! and the collection editor is not coming up? or is the Add button disabled?  why cant you add?  (the issues DO get intertwined, sorry),  If the Editor comes up, the test is to see if you can Add an X key when there is an X key in the mix already (collection editor WILL call/use your Add method, add `Console.Beep` to it to see when/how often and to verify yours and not the base class one is called

Comment: No the add button exists. The collection contains the items even after adding but after I debug or run the application the collection get emptied..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56125/discussion-between-plutonix-and-crazy-php-man).